# Is there any published research into the Mighty Thor gambit against the French Defense?

Tags: opening, french-defense, gambits

Are there any annotations on the obscure Mighty Thor Gambit?

```
[FEN ""]
1.e4 e6 2.a3 d5 3.e5 c5 4.b4
```

(which is different from The Wing Gambit:)

```
[FEN ""]
1.e4 e6 2.Nf3 d5 3.e5 c5 4.b4
```

At a tournament where it was played numerous players referred to it as "The Mighty Thor Gambit" but I've not seen that mentioned anywhere online.

Comment: But it is not the wing gambit.  The move order is distinct and the resulting positions quite different.

Comment: My book doesn't even know 2.a3 so I guess it's just worse version of the more serious 2.Nf3 followed by 4.b4. I always say about such a moves that they are over flexible, you don't know, which piece will go where, so you leave them in starting position and move with wing pawns...

Comment: A main difference between it and the Wing gambit is that White doesn't commit the Knight to f3 and can therefore play f4.

Comment: What tournament was it played at? Who played it? That might provide some useful context.

Comment: It was in a USATW so not a GM game, but I have found a few examples on chesstempo

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any published analysis nor commented games in this line.

Note that Black can almost forcefully transpose into a 'regular' wing gambit with 4...Nc6 5.Nf3 [5.f4, 5.bc5, and 5.Bb2 cb4 all look worse] cb4.

In case he is looking for more original play, 4...d4, 4/5...Qb6, 4/5...Qc7 all look interesting and try to demonstrate that a3 might not be the most useful move for White when Black refrains from taking on b4.